# MVC form, input tag populated with other value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

So I have a big form, which is divided in sections.
For simplyfying the thing, each section has input file tag for uploading a file, and an image of the previous file attached to that section (image in .png format).

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Upload Section Preview Image:
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="at-at-holder-N-TemplatePreview">
                <input type="file" id="TemplateSectionPreview" name=@sectionScreenshotName title="Attach" />
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="section-panel">
                <a href="#section-image-preview-@sectionId" role="button" data-toggle="modal"><img class="thumbnail" src="/Content/screenshots/@sectionScreenshotName" /></a>
                <div id="section-image-preview-@sectionId" class="modal hide section-image-window">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <a href="#" class="close imager thumbnail" data-dismiss="modal"><img src="/Content/screenshots/@sectionScreenshotName" style="max-height: 500px; padding: 4px;" /></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

When I submit my form to save changes, in my controller I take a look at the Request.Files, and I find as many files as sections.
Digging more, I find out that MVC sends in every input I declare, the image I show next to it. Even if I attach a file with the input, nothing changes.
How can I just make my controller to read just the file/s attached with the input?

my controller heading:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult QuestionEditor(FormCollection collection) 
{
...
```

Comment: How do you submit inputs? Are they located in the same form?

Comment: You can either split inputs into different forms or send request by yourself with javascript

Comment: I do document.getElementById('mainform').submit();

Comment: what I want is: when I submit the whole form with that button, just get in the controller the files that I introduced in the input fields.

Comment: and why this is happening in my form?